# How to remove an extension to a blob caused by morphology

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy

I have an image that I'm eroding and dilating like so:

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/1
        eroded_img = cv2.erode(self.inpainted_adjusted_image, kernel, iterations=10)
        dilated_img = cv2.dilate(eroded_img, kernel, iterations=10)
```

Here's the result of the erosion and dilation:

[image]

and then I'm taking a threshold of it like so:

```
self.thresh = cv2.threshold(dilated_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

But the threshold gives me an unwanted extension that I've marked in the image below (The region above the red line is the unwanted region):

[image]

How do I get rid of this unwanted region? Is there a better way to  do what I'm doing?

Comment: Use a circular structuring element, it will be much slower, but it will reduces the artifacts.

Comment: @FiReTiTi, could tell me a little more about it? In the context of Python, if possible.

Comment: I don't use python, so I don't know which structuring element is available. But a circular one preserves the distances (euclidian neighborhood/distance), contrary to the square (manhattan distance).

Comment: Are you sure that the region ABOVE the red lin is the unwanted region?

Answer (score 8):

Working with a different type of threshold (adaptive threshold, which takes local brigthness into account) will already get rid of your problem: The adaptive threshold result is what you are looking for.

[image]

[EDIT: I have taken the liberty of adding some code on Hough circles. I admit that I have played with the parameters for this single image to get a nice looking result, though I do not know what type of accuracy you are needing for such a type of problem]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.png',0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 210, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C)[1]
canny = cv2.Canny(thresh,50,150)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(canny,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20, param1=50,param2=23,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))


for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,0,0),3)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

titles = ['Original Image', 'Adaptive Thresholding', "Canny", "Hough Circle"]
images = [img, thresh, canny, cimg]
for i in xrange(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Let us know if this is not yet sufficient.

Comment: The problem with this method is, I can't play around with threshold values, because they vary a lot.

Comment: Fully understood, but without access to your original image(s), it is difficult to suggest a more general solution.

Comment: And what you want is (1) a good numerical approximation of the area of the bright spot or (2) a smooth contour for the area?

Comment: I want a contour, basically.

Comment: I don't OpenCV but as pixel coder... With those eye images, keep them colour (not grayscale) and start from the centre white or yellow and search pixels by spreading out until they hit a boundary (colour range that matches red outline). Basically just think how **you** would **see** the "blob" outline and write a program to do same. You follow the (red-ish) outline pixels and not let the veins break your concentration, so tell the computer to ignore colour of veins when passing those pixels, here it estimates where outline pixels would be & places them there. Result should be blob outline.

Answer (score 4):

From the binary Image it would be fairly easy to fit a circle using a Hough transform. Once you have the outer boundary of the circle i would suggest bleeding the boundary and cropping out the portion that outside the boundary.

Another approach is to adjust your threshold value. It looks like you could get away with that. You might need some morphological operations to get a clean edge. Using a disk kernel will help retain the shape to a good extent.

Comment: Hough circles is not a reasonable option because it's not always of a circular form. Could you please tell me a little more about disk kernel?

Comment: Ah!!! i see .. perhaps you could include that in your question. Just to clarify even though your image is not in the shape of a what would your final thresholded image look like ?  A disk kernel looks something like this https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/f9/47/Figure4.png . Essentially it is in the shape of a circle so when you erode it maintains a curved edge unlike a square or rectangular kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question has been rolled back to its original version, I have attached a solution using flood fill which works on your images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.png', 0)

h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)

gray = cv2.blur(img,(5,5))
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
print maxLoc

fixed_range = True
connectivity = 4

flooded = img.copy()
mask[:] = 0
connectivity = 4 #8
flags = connectivity 
flags |= cv2.FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE
cv2.floodFill(flooded, mask, maxLoc, (255, 255, 255), (60,)*3, (60,)*3, flags)

thresh = cv2.threshold(flooded, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

titles = ['Original Image', 'Blurred', "Floodfill", "Threshold"]
images = [img, gray, flooded, thresh]
for i in xrange(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]